# Етимологія форми майбутнього часу дієслів

Tags: етимологія

Нещодавно мені стало відомо, що в багатьох романських мовах форма майбутнього часу дієслів походить від інфінітива, до якого додається відповідна форма теперішнього часу дієслова *мати.* Наприклад, іспанське «працюватиму»: *trabajar + he → trabajaré.*

Чи можна сказати, что аналогічні українські форми утворилися таким самим чином? «Працюватиму» — це колишнє «працювати маю» або щось інше? Чому аналогічна форма відсутня в російській мові?

Comment: Вітаю на Ukrainian.SE! Цей сайт для професіоналів і тих хто вивчає українську мову, тому питання про інші мови (російську, англійську і т.і.) тут не обговорюються. Є принаймні 2 сайти на stackexchange.com де можуть відповісти на питання щодо російської мови - https://russian.stackexchange.com та https://rus.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Часткова відповідь.

Стаття «Дієслово» ([розділ «Історія»](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE&oldid=24028597#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F), підрозділ «Майбутній час») у Вікіпедії каже, що справді від дієслова *мати* (точніше, від його попередника *имати*):

> Другий спосіб полягав у використанні форм дієслова имати з інфінітивом (*имѫ писати*), причому допоміжне дієслово могло стояти і після смислового (*писати имѫ*). Від нього походить сучасна складна форма майбутнього часу, особові закінчення якої пов'язані з архаїчними формами дієслова *мати* (*я писати иму* > *я писатиму*, *ти писати имеш* > *ти писатимеш*, *він писати име* > *він писатиме* тощо), але роздільне вживання допоміжного і смислового дієслів трапляється досі в деяких західноукраїнських діалектах (*меш ходити*, *ме ся вмивати*).

Вони посилаються на навчальний посібник для студентів вищих навчальних закладів «Історична граматика української мови» Л. П. Павленко (Луцьк, Редакційно-видавничий відділ Волинського національного університету імені Лесі Українки, 2010), де на с. [116](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Pavlenko_Larysa/Istorychna_hramatyka_ukrainskoi_movy.pdf#page=116)–117 написано:

> Друга форма майбутнього часу складалася з допоміжного дієслова *имати* в теперішньому часі й інфінітива основного дієслова:
>
> Однина
>   1 ос. *иму писати*
>   2 ос. *имешь (-ши) писати*
>   3 ос. *иметь писати*
>   Множина
>   1 ос. *имемъ писати*
>   2 ос. *имете писати*
>   3 ос. *имуть писати*
>   Двоїна
>   1 ос. *имевѣ писати*
>   2 ос. *имета писати*
>   3 ос. *имета писати*
>
> Ця форма активно функціонувала в пам’ятках української мови різного часового діапазону, причому допоміжне дієслово *имати* могло вживатися і перед інфінітивом, і після нього, наприклад: *иму писати* — *писати иму*. Із часом відбувається злиття допоміжного дієслова в постпозиції з інфінітивом. Злиті (лексикалізовані) форми набувають значного поширення й стають одним зі специфічних для української мови засобів вираження майбутньої дії: *писатииму* → *писати* + *иму* → *писатииму* → *писатиму*. У процесі перетворення аналітичної форми майбутнього часу в синтетичну, тобто лексикалізації словосполучення, відбувається стягнення двох голосних звуків на межі слів в один. Залишки давньої аналітичної форми з допоміжним дієсловом *имати* трапляються в сучасних західноукраїнських говорах: *меш ходити*, *ме ся вмивати*.